# How do I install CamanJS in a ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js

I have a asp.Net  C# Web application, and use Visual Studio 2015. We want to use the client side image manipulation tool CamanJS.

However I have no idea how I can include the javascript files into the project to reference/use them.

On the web site it refers to package management programs to do the install. I tried downloading Node, and running npm on my base project folder - but errored due to a self signed cert in the chain (may be something to do with my companies firewall/security settings). However I am new to Node etc. so not even sure if this would install correctly into a .Net solution.

Has anyone ever done this, or has any suggestions. I am aware this is vague but I am stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [Google - "asp.net web application use javascript"](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net+web+application+use+javascript), [Google - "asp.net node js package.json"](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=asp.net+node+js+package.json)

Answer (score 0):

I had downloaded the package from the Camanjs website, I figured out I simply needed the caman.full.min.js file - which seems to have all the code I needed, so included that in my .net project. Added a reference to the script location, and was able to invoke the Caman methods. Turned out it was pretty simple, I just did not know that was the file I needed. Thanks to everyone who looked/responded to this question.